# Can't implement np.select

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1,2), columns=['A','B'])
df
conditions=[ 
    (df['B']<3),
    (df['B']>=6 & df['B']<9),
    (df['B']>=9)
    ]
PE_Categories = ['Less than 3', '20-30', '9+']
df['PE_Categories']=np.select(conditions,PE_Categories)
df
```

I got the following error:
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: full error message please.  But my guess is that the problem is in `(df['B']>=6 & df['B']<9)`  `((df['B']>=6) & (df['B']<9))`, extra () will solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another parenthese around multiple conditions. In your case `((df['B']>=6) & (df['B']<9))`.

The script should be :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1,2), columns=['A','B'])
df
conditions=[ 
    (df['B']<3),
    ((df['B']>=6) & (df['B']<9)),
    (df['B']>=9)
    ]
PE_Categories = ['Less than 3', '20-30', '9+']
df['PE_Categories']=np.select(conditions,PE_Categories)
df
```

output

```
    A   B   PE_Categories
0   0   1   Less than 3
1   2   3   0
2   4   5   0
3   6   7   20-30
4   8   9   9+
```